# How can I get all IP addresses of a subnet which run on a specific port

Tags: java, sockets, networking, p2p

I want to find all systems that are on the same local network i.e. that have the same subnet mask.

I think I must work with `InetAddress` Class in Java but I don't know what should I do.
My algorithm is:

> 1. Find all available system in a local network
> 2. Check if they run on a my requested port
> 3. Keep in mind the IP of system which runs on this port

```
InetAddress localHost = Inet4Address.getLocalHost(); 
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost);
System.out.println(networkInterface);
networkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost);
    
for (){
    networkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost) 
}
```

I think that the `networkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost)` can give me all available IP addresses in a subnet, but I don't how I can do this for all available systems, and what is the condition for the `for` clause.

Comment: getbyInetAddress returns the network interface on your machine which is bound to the specified network address. it doesn't tell you which addresses are in use elsewhere in the local network. Nothing you can do locally will tell you what IPs are in use. For that you have to probe routers/arp tables.

Answer (score 4):

Finding all of the *possible* IP addresses in an IP subnet is simple.  Just write a loop that enumerates all possible `byte[]` representations in the subnet and constructs `InetAddress` instances for them.

That's the easy bit, the hard bit is solving these two problems:

- how do you find all if the *live* IP addresses on a subnet, and
- for a given IP address, how do you figure out if it is using a particular port.

The first problem can be solved in two ways:

- You could use the `InetAddress.isAlive()` method to see if the host responds to a ping.  The problem is that some hosts may be configured to not respond to pings, or the pings may be blocked by an internal firewall.  This also doesn't work if the subnet is large.  The problem is that you need to ping a large number of hosts, and that will take a long time and generate a lot of network traffic ... especially if there are multiple application instances doing this.
- The smarter alternative is to examine your local machine's ARP cache, and extract all IP addresses that it knows about.  The problem is that 1) your application may not have the access rights to access the ARP cache, 2) some IP addresses may not be in the cache, and 3) there is no way to access the ARP cache in pure Java.

The second problem depends on the nature of the service on the port:

- If it is a TCP-based service, then you can attempt to connect to an IP/port using a plain socket.  If the connection is accepted, then the port is in use by something.  It may or may not be the service you expect, but in general the only way to tell that is to try to *use* the service.
- If it is a UDP-based service, then there's *now way* in general to know if something is using the port.

Comment: Finding all of the possible IP addresses in an IP subnet is simple. Just write a loop that enumerates all possible byte[] representations in the subnet and constructs InetAddress instances for them.... my problem is exactly in these sentences , how can i implement this loop and what method i can use??

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not willing to write the code for you.  Suffice it to say that it is a relatively simple task that anyone with a few months Java experience could do easily.  I'm not aware of any existing Java library that would do this.  (It is probably easier to write the code yourself than to look for a library.)

Comment: @hirad - lets get one thing straight.  SO is not a "write my code for free" service.  (If you need someone to do your work for you, hire a consultant.)  SO is a place for professionals (and students) to asking questions ... and get answers that help them *solve their own problems*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hope that you mean the following:

"I wish to discover all systems on the same local network as (the computer running my program)'s primary IP address which are listening to a certain TCP port."

With UDP, this is a slightly harder problem - you could look for bounces, but your packet may be eaten or lost (as could the reply).

Now, assuming TCP, you have three steps.

1. Get the IP address of the local interface you believe is the "primary" one.
2. Enumerate hosts on the same subnet as this address.
3. For each host, determine if the appropriate port is listening.

For step 1, use `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`.

For step 2, get the subnet portion of the retrieved address, and then try every possible host within that subnet. Let's hope it's a Class C and there are only 254 hosts. **There is no 100% sure way to get all the hosts without trying each one**. A non-100%-certain (and more complex) way is to use ARP tables to get a router's view of the network, to send a broadcast ping to the local net, or to fall down to layer 2 and send a broadcast Ethernet packet.

For step 3, open a connection to each host on the appropriate port and then close it. If the connection times out or is denied, scratch the host. Otherwise, add it to the "listening" list. You probably want to try more than one connection at a time and set the timeout interval to something small, since most people won't be listening.

Step 4: congratulations! You've just made a very feature-poor version of `nmap` in Java.

Comment: @hirad: the IP address is divided into two parts, the "network mask" and the "host mask". You keep the network mask, and try every possible host. So, "192.168.1.56/24" means "192.168.1.XXX" for every possible XXX from 001 to 254.

Comment: @hirad - there will be if you write one.